# C++/CLI help needed in MessageBox::Show

Tags: winforms, c++-cli

I am building a project in C++/CLI where in I have to show a message box in one of my forms.

The content has to be a combination of std::string and int.

But I am not able to get the right syntax.

I tried the following:

```
std::string stringPart = "ABC";
int intPart = 10;
MessageBox::Show("Message" + stringPart + intPart);
```

I also tried:

```
String^ msg = String::Concat("Message", stringPart);
msg = String::Concat(msg, intPart);
MessageBox::Show(msg);
```

Can someone please help me with the syntax.

Thanks.

Comment: What error do you get, or what problem are you having?

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d70a77b7-1508-4884-a5bc-106cf068b1be/how-can-i-show-messagebox-in-visual-c?forum=vcgeneral

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your problem is thar `std::string` is unmanaged and cannot be assigned to managed `System::String`. Solution is marshalling. See this MSDN page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384865.aspx

So here is the solution (for Visual Studio):

```
#include <msclr/marshal_cppstd.h>

// ...

std::string stringPart = "ABC";
int intPart = 10;

String^ msg = String::Concat("Message", msclr::interop::marshal_as<System::String^>(stringPart));
msg = String::Concat(msg, intPart);
MessageBox::Show(msg);
```

Comment: Maybe it's too late but there's no need for mashalling. `System::String` has a constructor that takes `const char*` or `const wchar_t*` so the solution is simple: `String^ msg = gcnew System::String(stringPart.c_str());`